# Autofac.Extras.Quartz with ConcurrentExecutionDisallowed not working

Tags: service, autofac, quartz.net

In my Windows service I am using Quartz.net together with Autofac. To assist me here I am using the Nuget Autofac.Extras.Quartz.
So far so good, but when I try to apply the DisallowConcurrencyExecution attribute it is ignored and multiple jobs are spawned.

I am using as follows:

**REGISTRATION**

```
builder.RegisterModule(new QuartzAutofacFactoryModule());
builder.RegisterType<CompanyDatabaseProcessor>().As<IJob>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

**SETUP**

```
var fact = container.Resolve<IJobFactory>();

_scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
_scheduler.JobFactory = fact;
_scheduler.Start();

var job = JobBuilder.Create<IJob>()
    .WithIdentity("QProcJob", "A3Group")
    .Build();

var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("QProcTrigger", "A3Group")
    .StartNow()
    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
        .WithIntervalInSeconds(executeEvery)
        .RepeatForever())
    .Build();

_scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

and when in my IJob, I check the context.JobDetail.ConcurrentExecutionDisallowed it is always set to false.

Comment: What about your job class, it has the DisallowConcurrencyExecution?

Comment: Yep. It is decorated.

Answer (score 1):

I see this question is old, but I encountered the same problem and I going to post my solution, so it could be useful to someone. 
The problem is that when you use JobFactory, the type of your job is unknown to quartz, so he assigns an internal type (NoOpJob) that is not decorated with DisallowConcurrentExecution attribute, causing that JobDetailImpl(the class that is used by quartz.net for IJobDetail) return false in ConcurrentExecutionDisallowed property.
What I did was a simple class that inherits from JobDetailImpl and add an extensions method Build to the JobBuilder class to maintain the same fluent code in the job creation. Here is the code:

```
public class SingleJobDetail : JobDetailImpl
{
    public SingleJobDetail() : base()
    {
    }

    public override bool ConcurrentExecutionDisallowed => true;
}

public static class JobHelper
{
    public static IJobDetail Build(this JobBuilder builder, bool disallowConcurrent)
    {
        var job = builder.Build();
        if (!disallowConcurrent)
            return job;

        var singleJob = new SingleJobDetail();
        singleJob.JobType = job.JobType;
        singleJob.Description = job.Description;
        singleJob.Key = job.Key;
        singleJob.Durable = job.Durable;
        singleJob.RequestsRecovery = job.RequestsRecovery;

        if (!singleJob.JobDataMap.IsEmpty)
            singleJob.JobDataMap = job.JobDataMap;

        return singleJob;
    }
}
```

And in the job creation:

```
var job = JobBuilder.Create().WithIdentity(id).Build(true);
```